# Different resx for different deployments c#

Tags: c#, deployment, localization, embedded-resource, resourcemanager

I'm using an embedded resource generated by 'PublicResXFileGenerator' which generates my ResourceManager class.
I'm trying to find a way to support multiple resx files for the same language or in some way being able to modify it from a deployed application but this doesnt seem possbible.

For example client 'x' is using the en-US translation:

- Flat

and the other client 'y' are using the en-US translation:

- Appartment

Maybe the above example is stupid but I hope you get my point.
Different users are using different namings for the same thing and I'd like to support this.

Is it possible?

Note:
My code is written in C#.

Comment: It must be embeded to your binary? I think, it can implement to load separated dll.

Comment: I'd prefer not to change the embedded structure. However being able to change the .dll would be interesting if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The strings in your default resource file (probably Resources.resx) are embedded in your executable file.

If you define a language specific resource file (e.g. Resources.en-US.resx) then Visual Studio will automatically generate a satellite DLL containing the localized resources.

The same applies if you add localized resources to a WinForms form, as shown here for Form1.

[image]

The satellite DLL is generated in a sub-directory of the bin directory.
The DLL must be deployed on the target machine in a sub-directory with exactly the same name.

[image]

This works for localized strings in any language, but **it works exactly the same for strings in the current default language.**

If the current default is en-US, and there is a satellite DLL for en-US, and it contains the required resources, then the .NET Framework will automatically use resources from the satellite DLL.

If you don't want the resources from the satellite DLL, no problem. Don't deploy it to the target machine. Then the .NET framework will use the default resources which are embedded in the executable.

If you only have two variations, then it is easy to manage in Visual Studio using the default resource file and an en-US resource file. If you have more than two variations, you are going to need a strategy to generate the resources. The simplest way would probably be to misuse another language.

Alternatively, you could use some other tool. [Winres](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/winres-exe-windows-forms-resource-editor) might do the job, but I'm not 100% sure.

Technically, you can define custom cultures, e.g. en-US-medical, or en-US-legal, but in my experience that is more bother than it is worth. I don't think (just my opinion) that Microsoft is strongly committed the concept.

Comment: Hello Phil Jollans,
Thanks for the useful information.
I've been thinking of a misuse of another language also, but this feels like an incorrect workaround even though it would probably solve my issue.
The dll files are however very interesting. Maybe I'll add functionality for changing the dll from the root.